# “Savoir pour quelque chose”?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions, verbes, registre-familier

In an [interview in *Le Monde*](http://www.lemonde.fr/technologies/article/2013/06/12/pourquoi-stocker-toutes-nos-vies-sur-des-serveurs-aux-etats-unis_3428857_651865.html), I've found:

> Le Congrès savait pour Prism, mais n'a rien dit.

Why “pour”? I couldn't find any example of *savoir* + *pour* in a couple of dictionaries I checked. Is it correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Savoir pour* is a colloquialism. Note that this isn't from a newspaper article but from an interview. This construction isn't formal enough for a newspaper article.

*Savoir pour* translates into English as “know about”: “Congress knew about Prism but didn't tell”. A more formal way to express this in French would be “*Le Congrès savait que Prism existait*” or “*Le Congrès était au courant de l'existence de Prism*”. Slightly less informal than *savoir pour* is *être au courant pour* (“*Le Congrès était au courant pour Prism*”), but I still wouldn't use it in a newspaper article.

The preposition *pour* is used when the description of what is known is elided, leaving only the salient aspect. In contrast, *de* or *que* requires a semantically correct qualification of what is known. There are a few cases where there is nothing to elide in the description but in most sentences only one of the prepositions work. This should hopefully be clearer with a few examples.

> Le Congrès savait que Prism existait.
> Le Congrès était au courant de l'existence de Prism.
> Le Congrès savait pour Prism.  *[« l'existence » is elided]*
>
> Je sais pour hier.  *[I know about the significant event that happened yesterday.]*
> Je sais ce qu'il s'est passé hier.
>
> — Tu sais pour hier ? — Non, je sais qu'il s'est passé quelque chose mais je ne sais pas quoi.
>
> — Tu es au courant pour la vitre cassée ? — Oui, je sais, c'est le fils du voisin qui a lancé un ballon.
> — Tu sais que la vitre est cassée ? — Oui, je sais, c'est le fils du voisin qui a lancé un ballon.
>
> — Tu es au courant pour la vitre cassée ? — Oui, le réparateur est passé ce matin.
> — Tu sais que la vitre est réparée ? — Oui, le réparateur est passé ce matin.
> — Tu sais que la vitre est cassée ? — Je sais qu'elle était cassée, mais le réparateur est passé ce matin.
>
> Tu était au courant de la promotion de Paul ?  *[“Did you know that Paul's been promoted?”]*
> Tu savais pour la promotion de Paul ?  *[this can mean that Paul was promoted but it can also mean something else related to his promotion, e.g. that it was turned down]*
> Tu savais que la promotion de Paul avait été acceptée/refusée ?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Could I say also "être au courant de qqch" or do I have to use "pour"?

Comment: *Etre au courant de quelque chose* peut tout à fait être utilisé : *Le Congrès était au courant des implications de Prism*.

Comment: @RickyRobinson There's a distinction in meaning, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

*Savait pour*, in this context, means *knew about*:

> The Congress knew about Prism, but did not tell.

I am not sure whether this is absolutely correct but this is widely used and admitted as such.
Another (and more formal) way to say this in French would be:

> Le Congrès avait connaissance du programme Prism, mais n'a rien dit.

or

> Le Congrès savait ce en quoi Prism consistait, mais n'a rien dit.